# how to handle this git rebase issue?

Tags: git

I'm developing a new feature, so I create a new branch, like this:

```
A--B--C--D              master branch
         \
          \-1--2--3     my feature branch
```

But given people is keeping adding code to master branch, I want to always to get latest code of master branch. Note, my feature is in a stand along directory, so there will be no conflict when rebase or merge to master. What I want is:

```
A--B--C--D--E--F
               \
                \-1--2--3--4
```

What git command should I use? Note that, I have pushed my feature branch to remote repository.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the command

```
git pull --rebase
```

Since you need to rebase on top of `master` (instead of `origin/feature`), you can also break that into:

```
git fetch
git rebase origin/master
```

(assuming your current branch is your feature branch)

Comment: $ git pull --rebase
You asked me to pull without telling me which branch you
want to rebase against, and 'branch.ntfdev.merge' in
your configuration file does not tell me, either. Please
specify which branch you want to use on the command line and
try again (e.g. 'git pull <repository> <refspec>').

If you often rebase against the same branch, you may want to
use something like the following in your configuration file:

    [branch "ntfdev"]
    remote = <nickname>
    merge = <remote-ref>
    rebase = true

    [remote "<nickname>"]
    url = <url>
    fetch = <refspec>